# Name Entity Relationship in UIMA

Tags: eclipse, machine-learning, nlp, uima, ruta

I am a newbie in UIMA, Currently I am stuck on below situation.

How to classify and relate different set of tokens that are obtained from an annotator in UIMA?
Like for person entity token set names like {John,Smith} and for assets entity set like {car,home}. I want to write rules to classify like the following xml.

```
<person>
  <name>john</name>
  <asset>car</asset> 
</person>
and
<person>
  <name>Smith</name>
  <asset>home</asset> 
</person>
```

Thanks for help in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe want to take a look at [UIMA Ruta](http://uima.apache.org/ruta.html) for a rule-based approach.

There are various ways to solve this in UIMA Ruta dependent on the preconditions and requirements.

Here's a simple example that processes a document like "john buys a car. Smith is home."

```
DECLARE Name, Asset, Sentence;
DECLARE Annotation Person (Name name, Asset asset);

// just to get some annotations
"john" -> Name;
"Smith" -> Name;
"car" -> Asset;
"home" -> Asset;

// span of relation
(# PERIOD){-> Sentence};
PERIOD (# PERIOD){-> Sentence};

// create relation
Sentence{-> CREATE(Person, "name" =  Name, "asset" = Asset)};
```

*(I am a developer of UIMA Ruta)*